# How to get child component(lightning-datatable) getSelectedRows() on parent component button event

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable

**I have one parent and one reusable child component**. The child component contains a **data-table with check box column**. The parent component has **many data-table>>child components**. On the button click event, I need to get each data-table selected rows. I used the below syntax on button click but always get null or **error** "*this.template.querySelector(...).getSelectedRows is not a function*"

**Parent-Component**

```
 <template>
      <div class="slds-var-m-around_medium">
        <template if:true={accountData.length}>
          <c-reusable-data-table
            data-id="overview"
            card-title="Account list"
            source-data={accountData}
            hide-checkbox="false"
            columns={accountColumns}
          ></c-reusable-data-table>
        </template>
      </div>
    </template>
```

**Rendered HTML**

[image]

**Button click event**

```
  handleSync() {
    debugger;
    var selectedRecords = this.template
      .querySelector("c-reusable-data-table")
      .getSelectedRows();

    console.log("selectedRecords are ", selectedRecords);

  }
```

**How to get reusable child component selected records on the parent component button click event?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to expose on child component an api method which will contain the `querySelector` method and will return the selected rows to parent component.

This [trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/communicate-between-lightning-web-components/communicate-from-parent-to-child) might be useful to you.

child

```
@api getRows() {
    return this.template.querySelector("lightning-datatable")
      .getSelectedRows();
}
```

then in your parent you can call this method on the `c-reusable-data-table`.

```
 this.template
      .querySelector("c-reusable-data-table")
      .getRows();
```

The reason why your solution is not working is that on the custom component there is not `getSelectedRows` method. This method is only on the `datatable` standard component.

Comment: thanks for your reply! I need one more help. Each time the child component checkbox is changed, the parent component needs to know, how total records are selected? On each change, I think your getRows() method fire resolve the issue. how to do that?